# ASP.NET MVC - How to display the Value of a Model that references itself

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a Model with ParentID that references itself.

```
    public partial class Categories
    {
      public long CategoryID { get; set; }
      public string CategoryName { get; set; }
      public Nullable<int> ParentID { get; set; }
    }
```

In the List View (Index View), I want to be able to display the CategoryName for the ParentID (where ParentID is not null)  and not the ParentID. For instance, what I have in the diagram below is showing blank Parent because I dont know how to go about it.

[Category](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CaJe7.png)

**Index View**

```
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr id="row_@item.CategoryID">
            <td>@i</td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CategoryName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ParentID)
            </td>

        </tr>
        i = i + 1;
    }
```

How do I achieve this

Comment: How is that a ParentID?  Your CategoryID is a long, but your ParentID is an int?

Answer (score 0):

I have replicated you Issue to solve it.

> 1. First i have created a Model.

```
public class Categories
{
    public long CategoryID { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> ParentID { get; set; }
}
```

> 2. A Controller with Index Action Method which return a List of Categories to Index View.

Code snippet

```
        public ActionResult Index()
        {

            List<Categories> li = new List<Models.Categories>()
            {

                new Categories { CategoryID = 0 , CategoryName = "Work" , ParentID = 1},

                new Categories { CategoryID = 0 , CategoryName = "Goods" , ParentID = 2},

                new Categories { CategoryID = 0 , CategoryName = "Service",ParentID = 1 },

                new Categories { CategoryID = 0 , CategoryName = "Buildings",ParentID = 1},
            };

            return View(li);
        }
```

> 3. Next we have created a static Method which can be accessible on View and this Method take ParentID as Input.
>
> After passing parent it will Get Category name and this will be return
>   to View.

Code snippet

```
namespace WebApplication1.Models
{
    public static class ManageCategories
    {
        public static string GetCategoriesbyParentID(int? ParentID)
        {
            string data = string.Empty;

            List<Categories> li = new List<Categories>()
            {
                new Categories { CategoryID = 0 , CategoryName = "Work" , ParentID = 1},
                new Categories { CategoryID = 0 , CategoryName = "Goods" , ParentID = 2},
                new Categories { CategoryID = 0 , CategoryName = "Service",ParentID = 1 },
                new Categories { CategoryID = 0 , CategoryName = "Buildings",ParentID = 1},
            };

            data = (from a in li
                    where a.ParentID == ParentID
                    select a.CategoryName).FirstOrDefault();

            return data;

        }
    }
}
```

> 4. View (On which we are calling static Method GetCategoriesbyParentID and passing ParentID to it. )

Code

```
    @model List<WebApplication1.Models.Categories>

    @{ 
    Layout = null;
    }

    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    @{int i = 1;}

    <table class="table">

        <tr>
            <td>CategoryID</td>
            <td>Bussiness Category Name</td>
            <td>Parent Bussiness Category</td>
        </tr>


        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {

            <tr id="row_@item.CategoryID">
                <td>@i</td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CategoryName)
                </td>

                <td> @WebApplication1.Models.ManageCategories.GetCategoriesbyParentID(item.ParentID)</td>

            </tr>
            i = i + 1;
        }
    </table>
</div>
```

> Output :-

[image: Output]

Comment: Is the static Method a Form of View Model or is it inside the controller. How do I do my Create and Edit in Action Controller

Comment: static Method it is used for displaying data , for taking input you can add text field which will be different

Comment: OKAY.. THANKS. How do i do my CREATE and EDIT

Comment: The ParentID will be a dropdown, and CategoryName A textbox.

Comment: Create a View Model with  1. List of Category 2. ParentID 3. CategoryName   . Then List of Category will be binded to dropdown with ParentID as Dropdown ID. and Textbox for CategoryName